# Vuejs update a value used with v-for dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-for

So I'm making an attendance tracker with Vuejs and Vuetify, and I want it to look like this:
A Calender made up of v-card components, and a list of absences read in from a database. I have my API set up and am able to retrieve a list of absences without any issues, but when it comes to putting them on the screen I have some issues. What I want to do is this:
The user selects the month and year. Each card then shows one day of this month. I have a function called `getAbsDate(date)` that returns a list of absences for the date passed to it. I want it to work something like this in each card:

```
<v-card min-height="170" tile>
  <v-card-text class="text-center black--text">
    {{i}}
    <v-sheet
      color="blue"
      class="pa-1"
      v-for="abs in getAbsDate(i+'.'+monthsNums[selMonth]+'.'+selYear)"
      :key="abs['id']"
    >{{abs["name"]}}</v-sheet>
  </v-card-text>
 </v-card>
```

selMonth is the month the user selected, and selYear is the year the user selected. This doesn't work however. I don't get any errors, the cards are just empty. `getAbsDate()` returns a list of objects. Any ideas as to why this doesn't work?
Thanks!

**EDIT**
Here is the declaration of my `getAbsDate()` function.

```
getAbsDate: function(date) {
  let l = [];
  this.absences.forEach(abs => {
    if (abs["start"] == date) {
      l.push(abs);
    }
    if (abs["end"] == date) {
      l.push(abs);
    }
    let day_start = moment(abs["start"].replace(".", "/"), "DD/MM/YYYY")    
          .toDate()
          .getTime();
    let day_end = moment(abs["end"].replace(".", "/"), "DD/MM/YYYY")
          .toDate()
          .getTime();
    let day_date = moment(date.replace(".", "/"), "DD/MM/YYYY")
          .toDate()
          .getTime();
    if (day_start <= day_date && day_date <= day_end) {
     l.push(abs);
    }
  });
  return l;
  }
}
```

The formatting is not quite right at the `.toDate()` and the `.getTime()`, but in my file it is, s it is not the issue.

Comment: Is your getAbsDate() a method ?

Comment: Yes, I define it in the method section.

Comment: Can you update what you are doing in getAbsDate method ?

Comment: Alright, I edited the question.

Comment: Try changing your `getAbsDate` to `getAbsDate (date) {}` instead of `getAbsDate: function (date) {}`

Comment: That doesn't change anything :/

Comment: Oh, I think I found the issue: I read data in the form of a JSON string from my API, and then I set this.absences to the parsed value of that. In the XMLHttpRequest,onreadystatechanged() I alert the value of this.absences and it works perfectly, but later on in the code the value is [], the default. I think it's because the `this` is not the right one for accessing the data. How can I fix this? It's not inside an arrow function.

Comment: That's why I asked for that change in `getAbsDate` function but you are saying it's not working either. Try changing your API call function the same way I asked for `getAbsDate`